# How can I lock a rigidbody's rotation on all axis? Bullet Physics

Tags: c++, physics, bullet

I am making a physics-based character controller however I have hit a roadblock; the character topples over.
I have tried to use SetAngularFactor() but that only locks the rotation on 1 axis when I need to lock all 3. Here is a basic version of my code:
`rigidbody->setAngularFactor(btVector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));`
All help is appreciated

Comment: You may want to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @LHLaurini why would I need a code snippet for this? All I am asking for is how I could lock a physicsobject's rotation on all 3 axis.

Comment: You say `SetAngularFactor` isn't working, but we can't help if we don't know *how* you're using it.

Comment: Please don't add solved to the title. Press the checkmark next to your answer when the cooldown lets you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so silly! I just set the x,y and z in `setAngularFactor()` to 0 and it works as intended!